# The Google logo is in the center of the MapView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

a few days ago I noticed that the Google logo in the MapView moved to the center by itself. (see image) I couldn't find what caused it. How can I fix it to put it back where it belongs?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as0U7.jpg)

this is fragments of my code

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        />
```

//////////////////////

```
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

/////////////////

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);   
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   }
```

Comment: Please show your code..

Comment: I added the code fragments